# Using IronPython to set "Data Limit by Expression" on a visualization

Tags: spotfire

How do I use IronPython to set the Data Limit By Expression field on a visualization?

[image]

(I mean an example of a simple IP script to set the Data Limit By Expression field on a visualization, I couldn't find one on the internet)

Comment: are you asking how to write the expression itself as an IP script? or how to set the "Data Limit by Expression" with an IP script?

Comment: The latter (how to set the "Data Limit by Expression" with an IP script?)

Comment: I accepted the edit but my corporate firewall prevent me from accessing  imgur, a link to which was introduced in the edit (I hope it works but I couldn't check it)

Comment: it's a screenshot of the dialog with the Data Limit area highlighted :) ps, working on your answer; I have to remember how I did this before.

Comment: Thanks on both counts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for any type of chart, if this is the only operation you need to do, you can use code like:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import Visualization

viz = v.As[Visualization]()

print viz.Data.WhereClauseExpression    # prints Python's nil value None
viz.Data.WhereClauseExpression = "[Column] = 'Value'"
print viz.Data.WhereClauseExpression    # prints the above expression
```

in this example, `v` is a parameter pointing to the desired visualization. you could also look it up by name or ID or some other method.

if you're already manipulating this visualization with a script and just want to add a data limit, you can add this to your existing script without importing the `Visualization` class. every visualization type's `Data` object has this `WhereClauseExpression` property